# How to group individual form fields into sections with Wagtail formbuilder

Tags: django, wagtail

How can I get get individual fields from Wagtail's formbuilder and show them as two separate sections (sides) in the rendered form.

In this form code below, name and select service is one section and others are other section how to use for loop and individual form field in wagtail.

**Goal layout wireframe example**
[image: Goal layout (wireframe)]

**products/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock
from streams import blocks
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.core import blocks

from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField

from streams import blocks

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel
)
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import (
    AbstractEmailForm,
    AbstractFormField
)
from wagtail.core.models import Page

# Create your models here.


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
        page = ParentalKey(
        'ProductPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='form_fields',
    )


class ProductPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    template = "products.html"

    productslist = StreamField(
        [
            ("title_and_text", blocks.TitleAndTextBlock()),
            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock()),
            ("simple_richtext", blocks.SimpleRichtextBlock()),
            ("cards", blocks.CardBlock()),
            ("cta", blocks.CTABlock()),
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )   

    header_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    meta_content = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) 

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thank_you_text = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('productslist'),
        FieldPanel('header_title'),
        FieldPanel('meta_content'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label='Form Fields'),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text'),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldRowPanel([
                FieldPanel('from_address', classname="col6"),
                FieldPanel('to_address', classname="col6"),
            ]),
            FieldPanel("subject"),
        ], "Email Notification Config"),


    ]
```

**Products.html**

```html
<form id="quickContact" class="bg-white p-4" action="{% pageurl page %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 font-14 ps-4" name="name" placeholder="ชื่อ" >
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <select class="form-control form-select border-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 font-14 ps-4" name="select_service">
                <option>เลือกบริการ</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 font-14 ps-4" placeholder="ชื่อ บริษัท">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 font-14 ps-4" placeholder="อีเมล">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control border-0 bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 font-14 ps-4" placeholder="เบอร์ติดต่อ">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
            <textarea class="bg-dark bg-opacity-10 border-0 form-control font-14 ps-4" placeholder="คำอธิบาย" rows="7"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mt-3 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-50 rounded-pill">ส่ง</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean a two 'section' form?

Comment: yes two section form..I have given image above like that image i need two section form how to do that

Answer (score 2):

- The approach taken by this answer is to add a special field type called 'section', which will be able to be added by the user in the admin interface to indicate the start of a section of fields.
- This approach is quite backwards compatible and will ensure any existing fields on forms or reports or templates will not break (even if no section is added).

### Step 1 - Add a 'section' option to your field types

- The goal here is to allow the user to create a field that is not a field but acts as a 'start of section' within the Wagtail admin.
- **Important:** You will need to run `./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate` after this code chance as you are modifying your `FormField` data model.

#### `products/models.py`

```py
#... other imports
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import (
    AbstractEmailForm,
    AbstractFormField,
    FORM_FIELD_CHOICES,
)


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey(
        "ProductPage",
        related_name="form_fields",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="field type",
        max_length=16,
        choices=FORM_FIELD_CHOICES + (("section", "Section"),),
    )
```

### Step 2 - Ensure that you can output the grouped fields as sections in your template

- We will now create a custom `FormBuilder` so that we can override the behaviour of how forms are built for your template.
- Without this you will simply get an error as the 'section' field has no way to know what should be rendered, the actual desire is to use this 'field' as a way to start a new section group.
- We will call this a `FieldsetFormBuilder` as it lets us group fields into a fieldset based on the usage of the section field type.
- Create a new class, code below. You can read more examples about using a custom `FormBuilder` in the docs https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#adding-a-custom-field-type

#### `products/models.py`

```py
#...other imports
from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import (
    AbstractEmailForm,
    AbstractFormField,
    FORM_FIELD_CHOICES,
)


class FieldsetFormBuilder(FormBuilder):
    def __init__(self, fields):
        """
        Assign the `fields` as a subset of the fields, excluding fieldset types.
        Assign the `all_fields` as the raw fields to be used when generating the
        fieldset data.
        """
        self.all_fields = fields
        self.fields = fields.exclude(field_type="section")

    def prepare_get_fieldsets(self, allow_empty=False, field_type="section"):
        """
        Prepare a function which will have an array fieldset data that contains
        the keys for the fields in that fieldset and the `options` + `id` for the fieldset.
        This function will be called as an instance method on the Form and can be accessed
        within the template as `form.get_fieldsets` which will return an array of tuples
        where the first item is an array of fields and the second item is the fieldset data.
        """

        fieldsets = [[[], {}]]

        for field in self.all_fields:
            is_section = field.field_type == field_type

            if is_section:
                options = self.get_field_options(field)
                options["id"] = f"fieldset-{field.clean_name}"
                fieldsets.append([[], options])
            else:
                fieldsets[-1][0].append(field.clean_name)

        def get_fieldsets(form):

            return [
                (
                    [form[field] for field in fields],
                    options,
                )
                for fields, options in fieldsets
                if bool(fields) or bool(options and allow_empty)
            ]

        return get_fieldsets

    @property
    def formfields(self):
        """
        Prepare a get_fieldsets method to the generated form class so that
        it can be used within templates and access the form for the final
        field content.
        """
        formfields = super().formfields
        formfields["get_fieldsets"] = self.prepare_get_fieldsets()
        return formfields
```

### Step 3 - Get your `FormPage` to use the custom form builder & ensure reports do not try to output section fields

- In your form page class (`ProductPage`), add an attribute `form_builder` to tell this form that it should use the custom class when rendering the final form to the template.
- We also want to update the methods `get_form_fields` and `get_form_class` so that the section fields are not output to the reporting system for form responses.

#### `products/models.py`

```py
class ProductPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    form_builder = FieldsetFormBuilder # important - must be added
    
    #... fields, panels etc

    # next two method changes will ensure that the 'section' form fields do not show up in your reporting

    def get_form_fields(self, form=False):
        form_fields = super().get_form_fields()

        if form:
            return form_fields

        return form_fields.exclude(field_type="section")

    def get_form_class(self):
        fb = self.form_builder(self.get_form_fields(form=True))
        return fb.get_form_class()
```

### Step 4 - Use the `fieldset` output in your form template

- The template example below is not exactly like your example but should present the simplest way to get to a two column layout (using bootstrap classes) with this approach (partially grabbed from the bakerydemo code).
- Note: Your example template did not include any error messaging or accessibility related attributes on elements, this code example includes those.
- The main part here is the `{% for fields, fieldset in form.get_fieldsets %}`, we can now iterate in our form over a fieldset (aka a group of fields) and inside each we can get a label for that section and the individual fields.

##### `templates/myapp/products_page.html`

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 form-page">
      <form id="quickContact" action="{% pageurl page %}" class="row bg-white p-4" method="POST" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.subject.errors %}
          <ol role="alertdialog">
          {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
            <li role="alert"><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ol>
        {% endif %}
        {% for fields, fieldset in form.get_fieldsets %}
          <fieldset class="col-md-6" id="{{ fieldset.id }}">
            {% if fieldset.label %}<legend>{{ fieldset.label }}</legend>{% endif %}
            {% if fieldset.help_text %}<p class="fieldset-help-text">{{ fieldset.help_text }}</p>{% endif %}
            {% for field in fields %}
              <div class="fieldWrapper" aria-required={% if field.field.required %}"true"{% else %}"false"{% endif %}>
                {{ field.label_tag }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="required">*</span>{% endif %}
                {{ field }}
                {% if field.help_text %}
                  <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </fieldset>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="col-12">
          <input type="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Notes

- MDN documentation on the `fieldset` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset
- Caveats with this approach - it may be a bit confusing to the user to see a 'help text' and 'required' option in the editing interface for a section. The required checkbox could be used to indicate the fieldset is required but this answer does not set up that logic. Also, this approach does not reach for any more complex Wagtail features like nested inline panels or streamfield because they will require some kind of data conversion with the old form data and the new.
- It would be good to point to the Wagtail formbuilder docs and advise that building complex forms may bump into the limits of the Wagtail system and at some point you may want to use Django's full form system. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html#form-builder